# Massive idle time before loading a page on Vagrant development site

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, magento-1.9

A file with some PHP code alone works well and fast, same for a file with MySQL connection queries. From what I can see everything seems to work well, except when trying to load any page in Magento. First load takes over 60 seconds, then Magento cache kicks in and subsequent loads are over 20 seconds instead, but the key issue is still the massive idle period before things start happening.

This cannot be because of VM Sync feature, because none of the website files are in the synced folder in this case. I have built scripts to pull out and mount specific directories to work on so only a small number of files need to be synced instead of the whole website.

I have searched, researched and tried all I could withing my human powers and I am still looking for a fix.
If there are any logs that would help finding the solution, please let me know where I can find them.

**Using:**

- Vagrant 1.8.4
- VirtualBox 5.0.24
- CentOS 6.8
- Apache/2.2.15
- PHP 5.5.38
- MySQL 14.14
- Magento CE 1.9.2.3

Had to use an older Vagrant version due to some SSH bug, and in turn I had to use older VirtualBox as well.

**The Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "package.box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.3.4"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  # The code below sets the VM memory to half of the host's and number of CPU cores to 4
  # None of the variations of those VM settings that I have tried affect the idle time when trying to load the site
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
    # Give VM 1/4 system memory 
    if host =~ /darwin/
        # sysctl returns Bytes and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024
        elsif host =~ /linux/
        # meminfo shows KB and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'`.to_i 
        elsif host =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/
        # Windows code via https://github.com/rdsubhas/vagrant-faster
        mem = `wmic computersystem Get TotalPhysicalMemory`.split[1].to_i / 1024
    end
    mem = mem / 1024 / 2
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]
    v.cpus = 4
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "resources/bootstrap.sh"

  config.vm.provision :shell,
    inline: "service httpd start; mount -a -o nonempty",
    run: "always"

  # Run these provisioners when needed with $vagrant provision --provision-with name
  if ARGV.include? '--provision-with'
    config.vm.provision "site", type: :shell, :inline => "source /vagrant/resources/build_site.sh"
  end

end
```

I used kaorimatz/centos-6.8-x86_64 base box, set up the LAMP stack, configured the machine further and packaged it as this base box.

PHP memory_limit also seems to not affect the idle time.

**Screenshots of page load statistics:**

- "Page load time" Chrome extension
  [Page load time extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvUR0.png)
- Chrome Developer Tools Timeline
  [Developer Tools Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU2Z1.png)
  The snapshots of the page along the timeline at the top must be the previous load, because nothing happens until the idle period goes through, after which the current page reloads and the DOM gets built again, in reasonable time by itself.

In the Timeline there appear to be those tiny functions (a bunch of stripes at the beginning, then spaced out until the big load period happens).
The top 6 lines of the Timeline at the beginning are repeated functions in each row:

Row 1: Timer Fired

Row 2: Function Call

Row 3: (anonymous function)

Row 4: C

Row 5: setTimeout

Row 6: Install Timer

Comment: and if you navigate from within the VM does it get any better or is it same slow ?

Comment: Same long load time, console commands and output: http://pastebin.com/x2D1L3Lw

Edit: running the command a few more times it appears to sometimes return good load times between 3 and 7 seconds, which doesn't happen outside the VM.

Comment: I checked apache processes with ps aux. Seems like every time I load the site on my host machine, one of those processes shows a number greater than 0 in the processor column(3rd) and a number greater than 1 in the memory column(4th) and they stay like that more or less, but the number of apache processes doesn't increase. http://pastebin.com/ebUp48eh

Also, weirdly, the VM wget load time checking shows a pattern of 2 quick load times and 1 long, then 1 quick and 1 long, then 2 quick and 1 long, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, albeit after looping around the actual solution for a week. Thank you everyone who tried helping.

To anyone building heavy development site systems anywhere, including virtual machines - the mistake I made and lightly passed by at first was that I mounted Magento's core PHP files over SSHFS to save storage and copy time. SSHFS still works perfectly for a huge media folder and less intensive Magento PHP file directories, but the amount of files run by Magento starting from index.php up to reaching the constructed DOM is literally crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say for sure if this is the issue in your case, but I've recently been working on a similar setup to yours and found that changing `v.cpus = 4` to `v.cpus = 1` in the Vagrantfile massively improved Magento page load times.  You'd think more cpu cores would be faster, but It turns out Virtualbox isn't very good at parallel processing as explained in detail here:

http://www.mihaimatei.com/virtualbox-performance-issues-multiple-cpu-cores/

and here:
https://ruin.io/2014/benchmarking-virtualbox-multiple-core-performance/

and here:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=64268

and here:
https://github.com/roots/trellis/issues/410

The core of the issue is that Virtualbox VMs with multiple vCPUs require that all allocated cores be free on the host before processing can begin. So with a 4 virtual cpus, every time Virtualbox schedules cpu time on the host it will wait until all 4 cores are available. This waiting time can apparently add up to quite a bit in the course of a page load.

Anyway try dropping the number of virtual cpus.  Hopefully it makes a difference for you.

Comment: That seems to change nothing at all. Oddly, some of the old development sites on the production server also take 14 seconds of requests, then load the DOM. Some other devleopment sites, same copies, load as fast as the live website no matter what branch they're on.
A default Magento site on the Vagrant box loads front page in half a second.

Comment: That's a bummer.  Performance debugging is so frustrating due to the many, many different factors.  With my Vagrant setup I'm getting 15s Magento admin page loads on one machine only.  Every other machine is much quicker.  Makes no sense.  Have you tried using Aoe_Profiler?  I've found that immensely helpful for this sort of thing.  http://fbrnc.net/blog/2012/08/magento-profiler